# ping: cannot resolve localhost: Unknown host OS X

Tags: macos, hosts

```
127.0.0.1 localhost
255.255.255.255 broadcasthost
::1 localhost 
fe80::1%lo0 localhost
```

This is my /etc/hosts file but it's really strange failure to ping and cannot resolve `localhost`.

It's work well like ping gonjay when I add

```
127.0.0.1 gonjay
```

to my hosts file.

Comment: Not a programming question - try http://unix.stackexchange.com ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I fixed it by making sure that hosts file used Unix line endings (I used Sublime Text for this)

Comment: Worked perfectly for me! Also using Sublime Text.

Answer (score 1):

I have solved the problem by restoring my Hosts file (it was empty):

But before, you have to check your hosts file.

> cat /etc/hosts

*If nothing is shown, that means your hosts file is empty.*

Then just copy and paste this over the existing hosts file then save it as plain text to restore it.

```
##
# Host Database
#
# localhost is used to configure the loopback interface 
# when the system is booting. Do not change this entry.
##
127.0.0.1   localhost
255.255.255.255 broadcasthost
::1 localhost
fe80::1%lo0 localhost
```

If your hosts file is not empty, your can try to delete it and add it again with this lines.

Answer (score 0):

Probably will help for those who don't know how make Unix line endings

```
brew install dos2unix
sudo dos2unix -c mac /private/etc/hosts
```

That will convert your perfectly fine hosts file to UNIX encoding.